# Android CoordinatorLayout hides/overlays main view

Tags: android, android-xml, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

I'm using the CoordinatorLayout and a ViewPager inside. The problem is, that the first entries of the List (in first page of the ViewPager) are hidden by the Tabs. When I use LinearLayout instead of the CoordinatorLayout, everything works fine.

1. How to fix that overlap?
2. Should the FloatingButton be added here or in the ListView XML?

[image: MainActivity]

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager_list_views"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/pager_list_views"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to ViewPager

```
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

if you use `CoordinatorLayout` you'll have to specifify a behaviour, it's safer if you control these aspects of your design.